# i want to use regular expressions to change the filename like this

Tags: python, regex, filenames

i want to use regular expressions to change the filename like this

```
1-30330036.jpg change to  1-30330036
1-30330036-1.jpg change to   1-30330036
```

how can i write my  regular expressions?

i have solve this question!

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you're having an issue with.

Comment: Are you actually going to rename the files, remove the extension and overwrite duplicate filenames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txt=["30330036.jpg","1-30330036.jpg","1-30330036-1.jpg","1-30330036A.jpg"]
regex=r"([\d+]-)?(\d+)(\w+)?(-[\d+])?.jpg"
result=[re.search(regex,s).group(2) for s in txt]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['30330036', '30330036', '30330036', '30330036']
```

Comment: but sometime we need to  change this 30330036.jpg to 30330036 and filename maybe is [a-z]

Comment: ["1-30330036A.jpg","1-30330036-1.jpg","30330036-1.jpg","30330036.jpg"] how to change to  30330036.  30330036 just filename, this filename maybe contain abc....@1pluszara

Comment: Updated my answer but still not sure what's your actual input and output!